# Based on mitzvot in Exodus 12:22 and Deuteronomy 6:9 - Was HaDam sprinkled on Mezuzot inscriptions?

Tags: passover, mezuzah, shemot-exodus, deuteronomy

**Based on mitzvot in Exodus 12:22 and Deuteronomy 6:9 - Was HaDam sprinkled on Mezuzot inscriptions?**

**[Exodus 12:22](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.12.22?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)**

> "Take a bunch of hyssop, dip it in the blood that is in the basin, and apply some of the blood that is in the basin to the lintel and to the two doorposts. None of you shall go outside the door of his house until morning." ( וּלְקַחְתֶּ֞ם אֲגֻדַּ֣ת אֵז֗וֹב וּטְבַלְתֶּם֮ בַּדָּ֣ם אֲשֶׁר־בַּסַּף֒ וְהִגַּעְתֶּ֤ם אֶל־הַמַּשְׁקוֹף֙ וְאֶל־שְׁתֵּ֣י הַמְּזוּזֹ֔ת מִן־הַדָּ֖ם אֲשֶׁ֣ר בַּסָּ֑ף וְאַתֶּ֗ם לֹ֥א תֵצְא֛וּ אִ֥ישׁ מִפֶּֽתַח־בֵּית֖וֹ עַד־בֹּֽקֶר )

**[Deuteronomy 6:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.6.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)**

> "inscribe them on the doorposts of your house and on your gates." ( וּכְתַבְתָּ֛ם עַל־מְזוּזֹ֥ת בֵּיתֶ֖ךָ וּבִשְׁעָרֶֽיךָ )

- As Mezuzot inscriptions became common for Israelites during 1st & 2nd Temple periods, did they sprinkle blood of the Pesach lamb around/under their Mezuzah inscriptions?

Comment: Are you asking about pesach offerings brought during temple times? Or about mezuah inscriptions during the original pesach offering in egypt?

Comment: No. Did Mezuzah inscriptions even exist during the first Pesach? - I was curious if Israelites continued the tradition of sprinkling HaDam on Mezuzot after the exodus & if Israelites sprinkled HaDam on Mezuzah inscriptions (after leaving the wilderness).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Pesachim 9:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Pesachim.9.5?lang=bi).

The placing of blood on the doorposts only took place on the first ever Passover in Egypt.

In subsequent years, blood from the Paschal sacrifice was placed on the altar, but not on individual's houses.

Given that, presumably, none of the Israelite homes in Egypt had *mezuzah* inscriptions, the answer to your question is no, blood was never sprinkled on *mezuzah* inscriptions.